# Checkbox won't check inside form

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, checkbox

I have a simple checkbox `<input type="checkbox"/>Click on this checkbox`, but when clicked, the checkmark only shows up if this checkbox is outside my `form`. If inside then it won't show. There is no CSS on this checkbox and no JS to interfere with it as far as I can see. Same issue on Chrome and Firefox and no errors in console. Any ideas?

Fix: `data-toggle="collapse"` was for some reason preventing the checkboxes from being checked

Comment: Please add more code ([mcve]) which can reproduce your problem. `<form><input type="checkbox"/></form>` works fine in my Chrome and should do so in every browser.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post the code you are working with and allow us to replicate the issue.

Comment: @corix010 Guessing at what the OP's code might be will always get you down votes.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I believe his description is simple enough not to resort to guessing. I tried to help out by showing him a working code so he can compare to his and realize his mistake.

Comment: @corix010 Well, the OP's code doesn't work and we don't know why because it wasn't posted. All we know is that you wrote working code. So, how does that inform the OP as to what they did wrong? How does that help anyone else who finds this question? Remember, Stack Overflow is a knowledge base. Answers need to be clear enough to help others as well as the OP. Your answer doesn't do this.

Comment: @corix010 As you can now see, the problem was not at all related to the code you provided in your answer. This is why we don't answer questions without code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus point taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. I had `data-toggle="collapse"` in the form tag. Once I took it out it works.

Comment: You really should go back and edit your original question to include the code you had to start with. You should have also tagged your question with `bootstrap` since that appears to have been the problem.